# Are both sentences correct? Why? "I have never done any public speaking." vs "I never have any public speaking done. "

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect

these are my following questions:
whether both sentences are correct and these two sentences can be substituted each other?
does the first sentence use a perfect tense and the phrase "any word speaking" is an object?
is the grammar structure of the second sentence a "subject + causative verb + object + verb (pest principle)"? (like the pattern as "I have my hair cut").
these two sentences just changed its word order, and then one uses perfect tense, the other is not?
thank you for your kindness solution.

Comment: To 'have something done' is to cause somebody else to do it for you, but this wouldn't make any sense in relation to public speaking.

Comment: @KateBunting - I have done public speaking as the speaker in question. I have also had public speaking done by employing a guest lecturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Kate Bunting. Here is a little more detail.

If you "have public speaking done" then this is present tense and you employ others to do the speaking for you. (causative)

If you "have done public speaking", it is present perfect and you did the speaking yourself in the past.